# User input validation with validation on properties

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, exception, error-handling

I have a `Name` Property in one class, that contains some validations:

```
public string Name
{
    get { return name; }

    set 
    {
        if (! RegEx.IsMatch(value, "\w{1-35}"))
           throw new Exception("Name must be 1-35 alfanum");
        this.name = value;
    }
}
```

When I bind this property to the `"Text"` property of a `TextBox` control in a WinForm application, the user inputted value will be validate with this rule, so how can I catch this exception and show it with an `ErrorProvider` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding binding to your control, subscribe to it's [`Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event (occurs when the value of a data-bound control changes):

```
textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", person, "Name");
textBox1.DataBindings["Text"].Parse += Binding_Parse;
```

Then in event handler do following:

```
void Binding_Parse(object sender, ConvertEventArgs e)
{
    var binding = (Binding)sender;
    try
    {
        binding.Parse -= Binding_Parse; // remove this event handler
        binding.WriteValue(); // try write control's value to data source
        errorProvider1.SetError(binding.Control, "");
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        errorProvider1.SetError(binding.Control, error.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        binding.Parse += Binding_Parse; // subscribe back
    }
}
```

You need to remove and add handler, because you are writing control's value manually. That will cause writing value back from data source to control and raising this event again. So, to avoid stack overflow, you need this trick.

You can reuse same event handler for all data bindings you have:

```
foreach (Control control in Controls)
    foreach (Binding binding in control.DataBindings)
        binding.Parse += Binding_Parse;
```

Comment: @Masoud after you setup bindings of your controls. E.g. in form constructor or on `Form_Load`

Comment: I used your codes in my application, but Set method of Name property fires after the Binding_Parse completed, and consequently, errorprovider doesn't show any error. WriteValues() doesn't call the Set of Name property!

Comment: @Masoud if you have specified binding correctly, then `WriteValues()` should write value from control to bound property of datasource. Just verified - works fine to me. Use debugger to see binding settings in event handler

Comment: I just used this code : `Binding b = new Binding("Text", BsPerson, "Name", true);        b.Parse += valueParameter_Parse;`

Comment: @Masoud you should add this binding to textbox bindings

Comment: I've added it to TextBox binding!

Comment: @Masoud what do you mean by that? I see code where you create binding, but where do you add it?

Comment: After create Binding, I wrote MyTextBox.Binding.Add(b);

Comment: @Masoud it should be `MyTextBox.DataBindings.Add(b);`

Comment: Sorry, I wrote mistakenly in last comment, in my program I wrote MyTextBox.DataBindings.Add(b);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42359/discussion-between-lazyberezovsky-and-masoud)

Comment: Sorry, my program had another problem, I test your code in another program, it worked correctly.